# get error when adding a user to a group site permissions - SharePoint 2010 on premises

Tags: permissions, security

I need some help here .
Not sure if anyone as gone through this before.
But when i try to add user to a group or to anything in sharepoint via site permissions i get an error and a coreelation id.
I had a  look at the logs but cant see anything strange.
If anyone has gone through this can you hint me.

Apart from the log files what else can i look at ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is there any orphan user in site?

Comment: If you call SPWeb.EnsureUser() for that particular user via PowerShell, what happens?

Comment: thanks Wahas when you say orphan user what do you mean and what should i bee looking for and how?

Comment: Hi nsturdivant i just ran EnsureUser and passed in the login username and it returned the userlogin and display name and added the user to the users list but when i try to grant it permission still get the error

Comment: Just wanted to update i could add the user via using powershell but not through the GUI :(

Comment: Anyone knows why i can't add users to groups via site permissions from the GUI?